# Scan barcodes from a mobile web site?

Tags: web-services, mobile, barcode-scanner

What is the best solution to scan barcodes and QR codes from a mobile web site (no phonegap etc...)?
The solution has to work on Android, iOS and Windows Phone.

I've heard about pic2shop, does it work well (even on windows phone)?
Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nothing seems to come out, I'll explain the best solution I found.

The thing is to use the app "pic2shop". It is a barcode scanning app that is available on Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8.
It is possible to request this app from a web page, let it scan the barcode and then callback you web site with the scanned information.

```
window.location="pic2shop://scancallback=http%3A//www.google.com/m/
products%3Fg‌l%3Dus%26source%3Dmog%26hl%3Den%26source%3Dgp
2%26q%3DEAN%26btnProductsHome%3DSear‌​ch%2BProducts
```

The above example will open the app and when the user scans a barcode, open the web browser on a google search for the scanned product barcode.

If pic2shop is not installed on the phone, the call will fail. The thing is to set a timeout that will redirect to the store (to download the app) if the call fails.
User agents can be used to know to which store it should redirect.

Full example (Android store redirection) :

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
         function trygoogle() {
          setTimeout(function() {
          // if pic2shop not installed yet, go to App Store
          window.location = "market://details?id=com.visionsmarts.pic2shop";
         }, 25);
         // launch pic2shop and tell it to open Google Products with scan result
         window.location="pic2shop://scan?callback=http%3A//www.google.com/m/products%3Fgl%3Dus%26source%3Dmog%26hl%3Den%26source%3Dgp2%26q%3DEAN%26btnProductsHome%3DSearch%2BProducts";
         }
</SCRIPT>
```

Documentation : http://www.pic2shop.com/developers.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for mobile web. You need access to the camera. GetUserMedia is only supported in the latest versions of android. iOS and windows phone don't support it yet.

Comment: Actually there are solutions. I identified two of them : request the "pic2shop" app from the web site or use the web implementation of zxing. I was looking for a possible other better solution that would work well on the three os I mentionned.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do you know how they work in mobile safari without getusermedia to access the camera?

Comment: You can call apps from a webpage.  For exemple this : window.location="pic2shop://scan?callback=http%3A//www.google.com/m/products%3Fgl%3Dus%26source%3Dmog%26hl%3Den%26source%3Dgp2%26q%3DEAN%26btnProductsHome%3DSearch%2BProducts ; will call pic2shop (barcode scanning app) and make a google search with the scanned barcode.This way you don't need to call the camera yourself as, in this case, pic2shop will do it for you. I'll answer my post to explain it better if nobody comes with something else.